# Killing field defines a jacobi field

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

I have a Killing vector field $X$ on $(M,g)$. Why, if $\gamma$ is a geodesic, is $X_{\gamma(t)}$ a Jacobi field?

Any hints to get started would be welcome

Answer (score 4):

What have you tried? A good place to start is the following: let $\gamma$ be a geodesic, and consider a geodesic variation of $\gamma$; that is a map $\gamma(\cdot,\cdot):[0,T]\times(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\to M$ such that $\gamma(t,0)=\gamma(t)$ and $\gamma(\cdot,s)$ is a geodesic for all $s\in(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon).$ Try and show that the vector field along $\gamma(t)$ given by $$Y(t):=\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\gamma(t,s)\right|_{s=0}$$ is a Jacobi field along $\gamma$. Once you have this your result will follow if you show that the Killing field $X$ induces a geodesic variation of $\gamma$.

Comment: thanks. So I define $\tilde{\gamma}:[0,T]\times (-\epsilon,\epsilon)\rightarrow M:(t,s)\mapsto \varphi_s(\gamma(t))$ then $\tilde{\gamma}(t,0) = \gamma(0)$ and since the flow's are isometries, $\tilde{\gamma}(\cdot,s)$ is a geodesic. It remains to see that $X_{\gamma(t)} = \frac{\partial}{\partial s}\tilde{\gamma}(t,s)\vert_{s = 0}$ but this is true by definition of the flow.

Comment: That sounds about right! Showing that the vector field determined by a geodesic variation is a Jacobi field is nothing more than a direct computation

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:  Assume that $X$ is a Killing vector field, then
$$g\left(D_YX,Z\right)+g\left(D_ZX,Y\right)=0$$
for any vector fields $Y,Z$. Now, let $\gamma$ be a geodesic with tangent vector $T$, then $D_TT=0$. To show that $X$ is a Jacobi vector field, you have to show that
$$D_TD_TX+R(X,T)T=0$$

Comment: Indeed; I realized my error while typing my comment but accidentally submitted it rather than delete it.